# How to access parent array variable/prop from child array in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating elements in React through arrays.

```
childArray.push(
    <span className={value}>
    </span>
)

...

parentArray.push(
      <Element>
          {({ value }) => (
              {childArray}
          )}
      </Element>
)
```

I want the child array to be able to access the parent prop `value`.

I'm using `react-final-form` with the FormSpy, which is when I ran into this issue. I can't change much about the situation I'm in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know how final-form might impact your code from what you share but using a function should fix your problem.

Depending on where it's declared you might need to pass `childArray` as an argument as well but otherwise:

```
function renderChildArray(value) {
  return childArray.push(
     <span className={value}>
      </span>
  )
} 

...

parentArray.push(
      <Element>
          {({ value }) => renderChidArray(value))} 
      </Element>
)
```